# a more elegant subscript

Tags: amsmath, math-operators, subscripts

I would need a suggestion to write a new command for superscripts and subscripts. the problem occurs above all with double pawns or with external paws to a parenthesis

Written in this way are really ugly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}         
       \item  $\bar{\epsilon}_{_{,t}}$

       \item $\rho_{_{0}}$ 

        \item $+2\nu(\overline{e'_{ij}u'_{i}})_{,j}$
 I would need a solution similar to this, I made several attempts but without success:
         \item $\bar{\epsilon}_{\scalebox{.9}{$\scriptscriptstyle ,t$}}$


    \end{document}
```

thank you

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with a ‘double pawn’ or ‘external paws’, nor what you're trying to achieve. Could you explain more?

Comment: @Bernard : the idea is to use the `\scalebox` command to choose the subscript size. in this way avoid using too many braces `_{_{,t}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just want to supply an empty superscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ds}[1]{_{_{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item Smaller subscripts

$\bar{\epsilon}\ds{,t}$

$\rho\ds{0}$

$+2\nu(\overline{e'_{ij}u'_{i}})\ds{,j}$

\item Normal subscripts

$\bar{\epsilon}_{,t}$

$\rho_{0}$

$+2\nu(\overline{e'_{ij}u'_{i}})_{,j}$

\item Lowered subscripts

$\bar{\epsilon}^{}_{,t}$

$\rho^{}_{0}$

$+2\nu(\overline{e'_{ij}u'_{i}})^{}_{,j}$

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: we thought of this type of `newcommand`, but I would like to use a new command that uses`{\ scalebox {.8} {$ \ scriptscriptstyle, t $}`

Comment: @Antonio With an unreadable character?

Comment: I found an interesting solution `\newcommand{\dsII}[1]{\scalebox{.8}{$\scriptscriptstyle #1$}}` or `\newcommand{\dsIII}[1]{\scalebox{.8}{$\scriptscriptstyle _{#1}$}}`. I thought about understanding the different possible options. I am relatively new with the Latex and I would like to understand many things.